# Are the OVA of "Baka and Test" more closely related to the manga/light novels than the anime's first season?

Tags: baka-and-test

During the rounds where Aki and Yūji face off against Kyōji and Yūka, Yūji reveals a photo album of Kyōji cross-dressing which came from when he lost to Class F in the first season and was forced to obey Yūji and cross-dressed for a day.

The difference between the anime and the manga/light novels is that photos of Kyōji cross-dressing were taken in private by Kōta which Yūka found the dumped him. In the anime, she sees him cross-dressing when Class C (along with Classes D and E) ganged up on Class A in Mock Wars to tire them out before the real War between Class A and F.

However, in the OVA it explains how Kōta took the photos and afterward Yūka is looking through them, burns the album and dumps Kyōji almost as if she never saw him cross-dressing during the Mock Wars.

I am wondering, does the OVA of *Baka and Test* more closely adapt to the manga/light novels than the first season of the anime did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

The OVA, titled [*Baka to Test to Shoukanjuu: Matsuri*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/9471/Baka_to_Test_to_Shoukanjuu__Matsuri) (*Matsuri* = festival), is based on the school festival episode in the 2nd volume of *the original source, which is the light novel*. (Source: [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%A8%E5%8F%AC%E5%96%9A%E7%8D%A3#.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1))

> **OVA**
>
> [...] 原作2巻を元にした学園祭のエピソード。 [...]

---

Additional info: [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%A8%E5%8F%AC%E5%96%9A%E7%8D%A3#.E7.89.B9.E5.BE.B4) also mentions that the story development between the original source and anime's 1st season is different, and even included a lot of anime original story. The 2nd season continues the 1st season's setting while also adapting the original source more faithfully.

> **特徴**
>
> - 第1期は原作とは異なるストーリー展開、及びアニメオリジナルの展開が多い。第2期は第1期の設定を引き継ぎつつも、原作を忠実に再現している。 [...]